# Expo stop audio playing after component closed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, audio, expo

I'm using expo's audio API for playing sounds.
I have a component inside a `react-native-raw-bottom-sheet` (Its a pop from the bottom of the screen), where I have the audio logics.

When I close the popup I want the audio to stop playing. I tried using a cleanup function in the audio component, but I got an error:
`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

Main component:

```
<RBSheet
  //props
  onClose({() =>{
  //maybe do something here
 }}
 >
  <Audio /> //this is the adudio component
<RBSheet>
```

Audio component:

```
 const [soundStatus, setSoundStatus] = useState({ status: null, icon: play });
 const [audioStatus, setAudioStatus] = useState(0);

 useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    if (soundStatus.status) {
      if (soundStatus.status.isLoaded) {
        sound.stopAsync().then(() => {
          if (mounted) {
            setSoundStatus({ status: st, icon: play });
            setAudioFinished(false);
          }
        });
      }
    }
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had two probelms. The first one was that in the `onPlaybackStatusUpdate` function I tried to update a `<Text>` with the remaining audio status when the component was already unmounted so It gave an error. I fixed this with adding `if(mountedRef.current)` in the `onPlaybackStatusUpdate` function.

The second problem I had that I tried to run the cleanup function in an empty `useEffect dependency array` ( `useEffect(() => {},[])`). The cleanup function ran, but the sound was null, so It couldn't stop the sound. I fixed it by adding the `sound` state in the `useEffect` dependency array, and checking if the `mountedRef` was true (described below).

```
 const mountedRef = useRef(null)
 
 //Tracking audio status changes

 //Fix of problem 1
  const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = async (st) => {
    //This is the fucntion which updates the elapsed audio status ( shows remaining seconds like this 0:10/0:53)
    if(mountedRef.current) 
      //set some state here for updating the audio status
  };

  //Loading the file for the first time
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (sound === null) {
      if(audioUrl) {
        try {
            const { sound, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
              {
                uri: `audioUrl`,
              },
              { shouldPlay: false },
              onPlaybackStatusUpdate //Problem was here
            );

            setSound(sound);
            setSoundStatus({ icon: play, status: status });

            console.log("setting sound");
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setSoundStatus({ icon: play, status: null });
          }
      }    
      }
    })();
  }, [audioUrl]);

  //Fix of problem 2
  useEffect(() => {
    mountedRef.current = true;

    return () => {
      stopMusic();
      mountedRef.current = false;
    };
  }, [sound]);

  const stopMusic = async () => {
    if (sound) {
      let st = await sound.stopAsync();
      if (mountedRef.current) {
        setSoundStatus({ status: st, icon: play });
        setAudioFinished(true);
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is in the `MainComponent` create a State Variable called `AudioPlaying` and manage the audio from that variable. Let me show you

add these lines to `Main Component`

```
...

const [AudioPlaying, SetAudioPlaying] = useState(false)

<RBSheet
  //props
  onOpen={() => SetAudioPlaying(true)} // Setting Playing to true when Sheet opens
  onClose={() => SetAudioPlaying(false)} // Setting Playing to false when Sheet closes
 >
  <Audio playing={AudioPlaying} /> // Pass the variable as a Prop here
<RBSheet>

...
```

Then in `Audio` component

```
// All Imports etc

function Audio({ playing }) {
  //Rest of your code
  const [soundStatus, setSoundStatus] = useState({ status: null, icon: play });
  const [audioStatus, setAudioStatus] = useState(0);

 useEffect(() => {
    // This useEffect runs whenever there is a change in playing Prop
    if (soundStatus.status) {
      if (soundStatus.status.isLoaded) {
        sound.stopAsync().then(() => {
          if (playing === true) {
            setSoundStatus({ status: st, icon: play });
            setAudioFinished(false);
          } else {
            // Pause your Audio here
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }, [playing]);

  //Rest of your code
}

export default Audio;
```

Comment: Give it a shot... Let's see.... As far as I understood your problem, I think this should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its on me, I forgot to mention that I don't want to play the audio right after when I open the pop-up. There is a pause/play button in the `Audio` component. So I just want to stop the audio if the pop-up is closed. But I will try your solution, maybe it works.

Comment: I tried this, still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

This is from 'expo-av' official document.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const [sound, setSound] = React.useState();

  async function playSound() {
    console.log('Loading Sound');
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
       require('./assets/Hello.mp3')
    );
    setSound(sound);

    console.log('Playing Sound');
    await sound.playAsync(); }

// This part is what you are looking for
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log('Unloading Sound');
          sound.unloadAsync(); }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);
```